# Defining and accessing the variables outside of loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to define or access the eight variables J1L, J2L, J3L, J4L and J1R, J2R, J3R, J4R outside of loop. To make it clear, here in the code, I am defining these eight quantities inside the loop, is there a way to define them outside? Or, as they are already defined here, how can I use them outside the loop. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
import numpy as np

def sweep():
    num_cells = 10
    phi = np.ones(num_cells)
    psi = np.zeros((num_cells + 1, 4))
    cur = np.ones(num_cells)
    mu = np.array([-0.8611363115, -0.3399810435, 0.3399810435, 0.8611363115])
    w = np.array([0.3478548451, 0.6521451549, 0.6521451549, 0.3478548451])
    tolerance = 1e-6
    max_it = 100
    err_phi = 1
    it = 0
    A = np.zeros((num_cells, 4))
    B = np.zeros((num_cells, 4))
    S = np.ones((num_cells, 4)) * 0.5
    Q = np.copy(S)
    L = 10.0
    sigma_s = 1.0
    sigma_t = 2.0
    dx = L / num_cells

for i in range(0, num_cells):
    for n in range(0, 4):
        smu = np.sign(mu[n])
        denom = 2.0 * mu[n] + smu * sigma_t * dx
        A[i, n] = (2.0 * mu[n] - smu * sigma_t * dx) / denom
        B[i, n] = smu * 2.0 * dx / denom

while err_phi > tolerance and it <= max_it:
    phi_old = np.zeros(num_cells)
    for i in range(num_cells):
        phi_old[i] = phi[i]

    for i in range(num_cells):
        Q[i, :] = S[i, :] + 0.5 * phi[i] * sigma_s

    #Boundary Condition
    for i in range(0, num_cells):
    psi[i, :] = 0.0

    # Right to left
    for i in range(num_cells - 1, -1, -1):
    psi[i, 0:2] = A[i, 0:2] * psi[i + 1, 0:2] + B[i, 0:2] * Q[i, 0:2]
        J1L = psi[9, 0:2] * mu[0:2]        
        J2L = psi[6, 0:2] * mu[0:2] 
        J3L = psi[3, 0:2] * mu[0:2]
        J4L = psi[0, 0:2] * mu[0:2]
        print J1L, J2L, J3L, J4L

    # Left to right
    for i in range(0, num_cells):
        psi[i + 1, 2:4] = A[i, 2:4] * psi[i, 2:4] + B[i, 2:4] * Q[i, 2:4]
        J1R = psi[0, 0:2] * mu[0:2]        
        J2R = psi[3, 0:2] * mu[0:2] 
        J3R = psi[6, 0:2] * mu[0:2]
        J4R = psi[9, 0:2] * mu[0:2]
        print J1L, J2L, J3L, J4L

    # Update phi
    for i in range(num_cells):
        tot = 0.0
        for n in range(0, 4):
            tot = tot + w[n] * 0.5 * (psi[i, n] + psi[i + 1, n])
        phi[i] = tot

    err_phi = np.amax(np.absolute(((phi - phi_old) / phi_old)))
    it = it + 1
    if it <= max_it:
        print(("converged in", it, "iterations"))

return phi
```

Comment: Have you tried using them outside the loop? They should still be accessible.

Comment: You are not using your function  `sweep` anywhere in the code. Also, instead of `for` cycles, you can use vectorized functions. For example: `smu=np.sign(mu)`. Numpy is very good at applying simple algebra to whole arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could define them at the top of your method by setting each variable equal to zero. The values will change in your loops and then at the end of the loop, the values will remain what they were at the end.

Comment: You don't even need to define them at the top. The variables will be created within the loop and will be accessible outside of it.

Comment: @Meg McCauley, I tried to define them in this way: J1L = np.ones(num_cells) and then within the loop J1L += ...... . But I get one error on the dimension mismatch.

Comment: @Jake Griffin, how can I do that?

Comment: @Harmitian That is happening because you are trying to set a single value to a whole array. If you do J1L[i] += ... you should be able to avoid the dimension mismatch problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the "+=" for two of the variables. For those, they will need to be initialized before the for loop (how do you add to something that doesn't exist?).

Comment: @Jake Griffin, I am sorry for the confusion. I wanted to try both ways. I mean initializing at top like Meg suggested. And for that, I need "+=". As you suggested, I tested I can access or use them outside the loop. Do you think I can use them outside this function or in a new function?

Comment: Why not just try it and see? ;-)